# After setting up dualboot Ubuntu 18.04 on 2016 macbook, I can no longer use macbook keyboard or touchpad

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, touchpad, macbook

So last week I setup Ubuntu 18.04 on my 2016 macbook as a dualboot, using a USB keyboard/touchpad.  During and after Ubuntu 18.04 installation, I observed that the macbook keyboard and touchpad were nonfunctional.  I follow directions here (https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver).  And found afterwards, that the macbook keyboard and touchpad were functional.  Great.  Fast forward to this week, and the macbook keyboard & touchpad aren't working again.  To make matters worse, I seemingly cannot log into MacOS any longer as during reboot, when I hold down the 'Option' button, I am no longer presented with the option of choosing the MacOS or Ubuntu.. it just loads into Ubuntu without user interaction.  Any ideas?